# Flask - authenticate with API redirect after login

Tags: flask, spotify

Using Flask and spotify API, I would like to implement this sequence:

**1. enter at my custom login page**

**2. have app authenticate user with API at submit**

**3. render homepage.html**

For this purpose I have the following code:

**Views:**

```
@app.route('/')
def homepage():

    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        return render_template('login.html')
    else:
        return render_template('homepage.html')


@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def do_admin_login():
    if request.form['username'] == 'user':
       session['logged_in'] = True
    else:
       flash('wrong password!')

    return redirect(url_for('index'))


@app.route("/index")
def index():
    # Auth Step 1: Authorization
    url_args = "&".join(["{}={}".format(key,urllib.quote(val)) for key,val in auth_query_parameters.iteritems()])
    auth_url = "{}/?{}".format(SPOTIFY_AUTH_URL, url_args)
    return redirect(auth_url)


@app.route("/callback/q")
def callback():
    # Auth Step 4: Requests refresh and access tokens
    auth_token = request.args['code']
    code_payload = {
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "code": str(auth_token),
        "redirect_uri": REDIRECT_URI
    }
    base64encoded = base64.b64encode("{}:{}".format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET))
    headers = {"Authorization": "Basic {}".format(base64encoded)}
    post_request = requests.post(SPOTIFY_TOKEN_URL, data=code_payload, headers=headers)

    # Auth Step 5: Tokens are Returned to Application
    response_data = json.loads(post_request.text)
    access_token = response_data["access_token"]
    refresh_token = response_data["refresh_token"]
    token_type = response_data["token_type"]
    expires_in = response_data["expires_in"]

    # Auth Step 6: Use the access token to access Spotify API
    authorization_header = {"Authorization":"Bearer {}".format(access_token)}

    return render_template('homepage.html')
```

but I'm getting `404 Bad Request` indicating that it breaks at the rendering point in `callback()`, like so:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jan/2018 16:33:18] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jan/2018 16:34:08] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jan/2018 16:34:08] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jan/2018 16:34:09] "GET /callback/q?code=AQD7AFv15x0ERvOVYftHen75sADbdn-xxV2fxScGNOyQbspyXeiM_FwmEnoHE7PsYTYJsOqoPj9KlE_dnCYVDBUg5bGTqk7kvNB9xr1fepDIgogo_oMTUesGYdF9Degqn2iKdgCZ5YBrLhTXpJ7Rtl8to4jkJ1L3xhtDb6r2ygDadSNgu_HLjB27RQz0RVuSGIw8jAIeRld6R6Sv_RT54Bi8SXZpdUNdXAyM09NLL2Tjn2Ziz1yiKFushg96BjkagoJANBdsCA HTTP/1.1" 400 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jan/2018 16:34:11] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your route to '/home' and redirect to it by using

```
     redirect(url_for('home'))
```

Note that you need to import redirect and url_for

```
    from flask import redirect, url_for
```

And it is also advised to have separate routes for login and home.

Comment: it is working now, with the configuration above. there was another bug in the code, not mentioned. thank you anyway.